# Cordova com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova

Pesquisei muito, mas não achei nada concreto.
Como abrir o cliente de email padrão do mobile utilizando cordova com angularJS?

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta não explica exatamente o que você quer fazer ao abrir o cliente de email nativo, mas se for para compor uma mensagem, basta usar o `mailto` no link:

```
<a href="mailto:email@email.com">Link text</a>
```

Além disso, você precisa configurar as propriedades do projeto, no config.xml, para direcionar o `mailto` para o cliente de email adicionando essa linha:

```
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Usei esse código e funcionou.